# convert: combine multiple imges to pdf but convert them first to jpg

Tags: convert, imagemagick

I have a list of image files which I want to combine into a pdf.

The ImageMagick for that is `convert myImgFiles*.png -resize 1000 myOutput.pdf` and works perfectly.

But now I first want to convert the input files to JPG and then combine them into a pdf.

I tried piping, but only one image is put in the pdf.
`convert myImgFiles*.png -resize 1000 -quality 80 jpeg:- | convert - myOutput.pdf`

Can this be done without producing temp files?

Comment: Why do you need to do it without temp files? This question is lacking info. If it's e.g. about disk space, I don't think anything will help you.